# What's the recommended way to install Wordpress from packages on a server?

Tags: 10.04, server, apache2, wordpress

I've got a LAMP server available from http://91.xxx.xx.xx/ (just an example IP address), and I'd like to install Wordpress there.

I've gone as far as doing a simple `sudo apt-get install wordpress` to install Wordpress, but I'm not too sure about the set of best-practice steps after that.

I've read the [documentation to install Wordpress in the Ubuntu wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WordPress), but it is out-of-date. Also I couldn't figure it out from the `/usr/share/doc/wordpress/README.Debian` provided in the [wordpress package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/wordpress).

Here are some additional notes of what I'm trying to do with the site:

- The server is running Ubuntu 10.04 LTS
- Wordpress and any other software required should be installed from packages from the official Ubuntu repositories
- I'm not planning to use juju
- Wordpress should be available from http://91.xxx.xx.xx/ directly (i.e. not from http://91.xxx.xx.xx/blog or http://91.xxx.xx.xx/wordpress)

I'd appreciate any help with the clear set of recommended steps after the initial installation of the wordpress package to get the site up and running, as there's lots of info out there, but it seems to be out-of-date.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. I am flagging this for closure :)

Comment: Similar issue. Installed from Synaptic and expected some sort of menu item to GUI to administer *something*. Why provide a Synaptic package without adding a menu item, leaving the user to have to start googling for how to get started at step 0? I also found a "readme" (readme.html, not readme.debian), the first thing is says is to go download WP and extract it, etc. Oh. So glad I just installed from a package.

Answer (score 1):

Using packages from ubuntu repos is a best way to get tested software but also be informed that it might take some time before you get new package updates and these updates usually come with new ubuntu versions. Okay so let's get started.

1. follow the link < http://wordpress.org/latest.tar.gz> to download latest stable wordpress package.
2. deflate (uncompress) its content to your web server's root folder. Usually `/var/www/`. Ensure that in the your web servers root folder you can find the following folders just to be sure `wp-admin, wp-content, wp-includes`
3. then go to your server address and begin the 5 minute install. You said yours is at `http://91.xxx.xxx.xxx`
4. if later on you want wordpress in another folder deflate the wordpress package to `/var/www/blog` if you want it to appear at `http://91.xxx.xxx.xxx/blog`

Comment: Thanks for your comment. As I was saying, though, I want to install from packages, not from wordpress.org, and I'd also like to know the steps following the installation, i.e. what's the recommended way to set up apache so that the wordpress instance appears at http://91.xxx.xx.xx/ and if there are any symlinks I need to create, etc. Your answer, although I appreciate your help (thanks!) does not answer any of those.

Answer (score 1):

I know this thread is a bit old but I still respond and share my thoughts since this is the only post I've ever found on askubuntu.com about utilizing `wordpress` from `apt-get`. After a few hours of try and error, I concluded that we better use source install from wordpress.org rather than using Ubuntu binary package from apt-get. My reasonings:

- [Official doc](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WordPress) did not work out of the box as of today (2/09/2014 while its last update was 1/31/2014, about a week ago). In my case I got an error and needed a workaround [1].
- Even though I was able to run `wordpress` installed from apt-get with the workaround I mentioned above, I ended up finding the working version was `3.3.1` (as [package.ubuntu.com says so too for Precise](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/wordpress)), when the latest available version on the server that's installed from source was `3.8.x`, and the Dashboard thinks it's the latest. I couldn't find a way to tell it the actual latest version is way more advanced. So here I agree with the advantage in [this comment](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2117472&p=12517288#post12517288).

My environment; Ubuntu 12.04 Server on Amazon EC2

[1] Error on browser when accessing `http://YOURDOMAIN/wordpress`

```
Neither /etc/wordpress/config-ec2-54-201-233-60.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com.php nor /etc/wordpress/config-us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com.php could be found.
Ensure one of them exists, is readable by the webserver and contains the right password/username.
```

Workaround: Putting aside two files by like

```
$ /etc/wordpress/config-localhost.php config-localhost.php.org && sudo mv wp-config.php wp-config.php.org
```

Comment: I mostly agree with this but there is one advantage to installing the package anyway which is that it will also pull all of the dependencies for WordPress. You can use `sudo apt-get install -s wordpress` to get a list of all dependencies without installing it though.