# How to get latest Wordpress on 12.04.4 LTS

Tags: 12.04, server, apt, apache2, wordpress

I have a server running **Ubuntu 12.04.4 x64**  , and want to install latest wordpress.

I have two options

1. use apt-get to install the package (sudo apt-get install wordpress)
2. install the latest version from wordress.org (wget http://wordpress.org/latest.tar.gz)

What are the pros and cons of each method?

I found through launchpad that the version for Precise Pangolin is 3.3.1+dfsg-1. Which I assume should be upgradeable through wordpress admin page to latest version (3.8.1 as of this writing).

So which method is better to install latest wordpress. BTW, I do have webmin/virtualmin running on my server.

Cheers,
Abdul

Comment: I haven't installed from `apt` but I would choose using the latest version from Wordpress. You get the latest version with current security patches and can install it in whatever directory your Apache setup is serving out. Follow the directions from Wordpress on installing using the "5 Minute Install."

Comment: sounds good, but apt-get method installs many packages `root@localhost:~# apt-get install wordpress

The following extra packages will be installed:
  libicu48 libjs-cropper libjs-prototype libjs-scriptaculous libphp-phpmailer libphp-simplepie libphp-snoopy
  libt1-5 php5-curl php5-gd php5-intl php5-mysql tinymce wordpress-l10n
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libicu48 libjs-cropper libjs-prototype libjs-scriptaculous libphp-phpmailer libphp-simplepie libphp-snoopy
  libt1-5 php5-curl php5-gd php5-intl php5-mysql tinymce wordpress wordpress-l10n
`

Comment: Complete Wordpress functions are provided within the Wordpress install you can download. Mine works perfectly fine without those additional packages.

Answer (score 2):

It's pretty easy to get the latest WordPress installed on Ubuntu 12.04. I do it multiple times a week.

As you've already mentioned, the con of using `apt-get` to install the `wordpress` package is that it's not currently up to date. If you do it this way, you'll still need to

- modify permissions on the directory root to update through the Admin dashboard,
- hand over your FTP credentials to update through the Admin dashboard, or
- download the latest release anyways and manually install the code.

Alternatively, you could just download the latest WordPress directly. This is what we have our users do.

Make sure you don't miss the following related AskUbuntu questions:

> [What's the recommended way to install Wordpress from packages on a server?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65264/whats-the-recommended-way-to-install-wordpress-from-packages-on-a-server)
>
> [How do I configure Wordpress to update automatically?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/163907/how-do-i-configure-wordpress-to-update-automatically)